# Why doesn't AngularJS service bind to scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, geolocation

Angular noob trying to follow [this geolocation](https://github.com/ninjatronic/ngGeolocation/tree/v0.0.4) example for watchPosition verbatim using Angular 1.2.21.  Browser debuggers show the service position object is updated when GPS fires however scope myCoords remains undefined.  I've tried adding $apply in a couple places which throws apply is in progress.  What's wrong here and which concepts do I need to read up on ?

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['ngGeolocation'])
    .controller('geolocCtrl', ['$geolocation', '$scope', function($geolocation, $scope) {
        $geolocation.watchPosition({
            timeout: 60000,
            maximumAge: 250,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
        $scope.myCoords = $geolocation.position.coords; // not updated
        $scope.myError = $geolocation.position.error; // this becomes truthy, and has 'code' and 'message' if an error occurs
    }]);
```

Comment: an issue has already been registered https://github.com/ninjatronic/ngGeolocation/issues/9

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your code in a $timeout?

Comment: but you sure what your $geolocation.position.coords contain the data what you need ? I mean you sure what it returns data at all and it not undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `coords` property of `$geolocation.position` gets re-assigned with every update. It's the `position object of`$geolocation` that stays the same.

So, (based on how you want to use it) you should write something like this:

```
$scope.myPosition = $geolocation.position;

<!-- If you want to use it in the VIEW -->
<p>Latitude:   {{myPosition.coords.latitude}}</p>
<p>Longtitude: {{myPosition.coords.longtitute}}</p>
<p ng-show="myPosition.error">
    Error ({{myPosition.error.code}}): {{myPosition.error.message}}
</p>

/* Or if you want to manually $watch for changes in coords */
$scope.$watch('myPosition.coords', function (newValue, oldValue) {...}, true);
```